# what is the script command for /etc on ubuntu

Tags: scripting, command-line, environment-variables, ubuntu-10.04

i need to access /etc through script command in ubuntu. 
for example, home is  ${user.home} and tomcat home is ${catalina.home}, if i wanted to access /etc what should it be? also if i wanted to access a custom folder under /etc, how should i do it? do i have to set up an environment variable to access it?

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a variable, just use "/etc". All *nix systems have it, it's pretty much guaranteed to exist.

Comment: there are cases where you need this variable, specially some libraries, if this is not mentioned, would start from their own directory, rather than the needed way.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare another variable ${xxxservice.etc} because you never know when someone (or some distribution group) will have moved your configuration (etc) directory to some other location other then "/etc".

My 2 cents.